# Debugging Vue Webpack Browsersync Docker bottleneck

Tags: docker, debugging, webpack, vuejs2, browser-sync

I started work on a project, and I’m working on the front end of a Laravel/Vue/SCSS application that’s compiled with crossenv Webpack in a Docker container.

But the compilation process is unbearably slow.   I press save on a Vue or javascript or scss file, and then I wait 20-30 seconds prior to reload.  In addition, sometimes it will reload multiple times/incompletely.

I need to figure out what is causing the bottleneck, but I don’t know how to debug it.  The output is lacking.  Is there a good way to see exactly what’s happening - like what command is being executed on what file  in real time - so I can find the delay?

Note:  I’m running this on Ubuntu 18.04 - 64 bit on a quad core i7 with 20 GB of DDR3 ram.